# create a multilevel list for right to left languages in ms.word

Tags: ms-office

I want to use a multi level list for persian language in microsoft word 2010. in english the numbers are as below:

[image]

in right to left languages (like persian) it should be like :

[image]

but I don't know how can I change it's direction for RTL languages. thx for your helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it for a depth-2 list:

1. Click the menu part of the Multilevel List ribbon menu-button.
2. Select "Define New Multilevel list".
3. Go to level 2 of your list (there's a listbox of the 9 levels).
4. In the 'Formatting for Number' textbox, place the cursor after the first dot (.) character (between the two numbers).
5. Insert a Unicode RLM (Right-to-Left Mark) a space for example.
6. Accept the changes you made.

That's it, now the numbers are in right-to-left order. Obviously you would need to do this for levels 3, 4, etc. with multiple RLMs.

Comment: I get the whole concept of your answer, but in doing part 5, how would you do that? when in type U+200F and Alt-X after that, nothing happens. what do you mean by "a space"?

Comment: You can get unicode RLM space by switching the keyboard to RTL language then type in a space

Comment: Even instead of space, RTM character ([`U+200F`](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=200F)) is enough. Of course, yes, the appearance of this character is hidden, which looks better.